# Sitecore 9.3 versions update date issue

Tags: content-editor, versions

We have set up workflow in Sitecore 9.3 version. After hitting Lock and Edit link on one data source item, new version will be created. This new version will have current date set to **Created/Updated** fields and this new version is in Draft state which is as expected. There is no change in old version which is in Approved state and all fields are non-editable.

This new data source item is being referenced on a page in one rendering component. In experience editor, we made content update in component and hit the save button. As a result new version of this data source item is created with current date set to **Created/Updated** fields but in old version current date is also set to **Updated** field and old version is in Approved state but all fields are editable. There shouldn't be any change in old version. Now new version is in Draft state but all fields are non-editable.

Is this a kind of bug in this Sitecore version OR we need to write some custom code to handle this behavior. If we directly edit item, versioning working properly. This behavior is happening only while editing that item via experience editor.

Comment: I would recommend submitting a support ticket.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After discussion with Sitecore support, I found that this has been fixed in Cumulative hotfix and here is the link
[**Cumulative hotfix for Sitecore 9.3**](https://support.sitecore.com/kb?id=kb_article_view&sysparm_article=KB1001332)

Hope this is helpful in case anyone facing same issue

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using SXA as I have already faced similar problem with SXA. You should make sure your pages inherit SXA Page template - /sitecore/templates/Foundation/Experience Accelerator/Multisite/Content/Page

Doing this will tell SXA that your pages are SXA pages and the handler related to FlagPublishingGroupingItems doesnt get triggered. This handler is based on below config and it is helpful to flag items to be published automatically when Publishing Service is used with Sitecore. If you are not using Publishing Service, then you can also set it to false and it shall work.

```
<setting name="XA.Foundation.Publishing.FlagPublishingGroupingItems.Enabled" value="true" />
```

You can read more about this issue here - https://ghanendras.blogspot.com/2022/11/old-versions-of-sitecore-pages-get.html

Comment: No. Actually we're not using SXA in project.

Comment: I recommend to look in similar direction. There must be a handler trying to update all items when a related data source item is updated.